# Specify How Parameters are Passed in REST service

Tags: c#, rest

I'm planning to create a REST service using C#, but am a little confused how to structure it.

In this basic example, there is one method that should write TimeSeries data.  From the research I have done, I expect the URL to resemble: http://myserver/v1/TimeSeries/{id}

Example: http://myserver/v1/timeseries/1
{["20180101","10"]["20180102","20"]}

In this example, the TimeSeries ID is 1 and the JSON (maybe not correct JSON, but illustrates example) represents the data points to be written.

So the ID of the time series to write is in the URI.  The actual data to be written would be in the request body (posted as JSON).

Here's what I have so far:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITimeSeriesService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "timeseries", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string WriteTimeSeries(int id, string datapoints);

}
```

So my questions are:

- How do I bind the method to the URI as described above?
- How do I specify that parameter 'id' is in the URI, whilst 'datapoints' is in the body?

I am using .Net 4.5.2

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Do you want to do a PUT on that url? Please note that is not a best practise to pass inside the URL a JSON

Comment: Do you **particularly** want to use `WebInvoke`? Would you consider WebAPI or ASP.NET MVC instead?

Comment: @Thecave3 I have selected PUT based on the advice here: https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-designing-guidelines-the-best-practices-60e1d954e7c9

Comment: @mjwills: Honest answer - I don't know!  Only requirement is this should be consumable from non .Net applications (e.g. Python or Excel)

Comment: @GinjaNinja first of all it is a REST service over HTTP, it can be consumable to whatever can do an HTTP request (I don't think Excel can do HTTP). Then i suggest you to use a better language shaped for webservices like Nodejs. Above all this I think you have to accept a request coming over so the json will not be in the URL field, but in the body field. Do you know exactly what is an HTTP request?

Comment: @Thecave3 You can reference VB6/COM libraries from Excel code-behind. If memory serves, there is an HTTP component available as such.

Comment: @KennethK. wow, whata day to be alive, even Excel can make an HTTP request. BTW json in URL is totally a bad idea in every case possible

Answer (score 1):

JSON is just a string representation of what in a an Object Oriented language would be a class and it's properties and fields.

For example in C# you might have a class like:

```
Animal
{
   public string Breed {get; set:}
   public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

the JSON to pass an animal to your (assuming Web API ) controller method would look like:

```
{"Animal":{"Breed":"Bull Dog", "Age":"5"}}
```

and in your WebAPI controller using default routing (`{controller}/{action}`) your method would look something like:

```
public string AddDog([FromBody]Animal animal)
{
   // do stuff with animal
}
```

Most likely with the above I'd expect a POST method with the JSON in the body of the request. WebAPI / MVC will try to route the method based on what best matches the request.

The URL/ Query would look something like:

```
 http://myApp:4000/Animal/Add
```

Of course, if you are building this to be used with another .NET App, you would just use HttpClient. That code would look much like:

```
// .net core 2 with extensions
var Client = new HttpClient();
var message = client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://myApp:4000/Animal/Add", myAnimalObject).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: POST is usually to create an object and PUT to update. It is a convention by the way

Comment: @Thecave3 Yes, I assumed that clear with the "Add" method, unless you are speaking for absolute clarity and posterity?

Comment: yes it is for clarity and also it seems that he wants to update something (see the question comment). In any case it is better to specify

Comment: @AustinTFrench: Thanks for the answer.  Why are you suggesting WebAPI rather than REST? Also, does having Add in the URI not break convention? (PUT for UPDATE, POST for ADD)

Comment: WebAPI is a .net implementation to implement RESTful services. As a .NET developer you can work with pretty standard C# / .net frameworks and concepts but to a consumer it behaves like any REST service.